# BLE: when writing characteristic, getting status as 133 in onCharacteristicWrite

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics

I'm trying to setup BLE client-server comm on android devices.
From the server side, I could advertise and see connection updates successfully. On the client side, I could connect to the server , discover its services and characteristics. However, when I try to write the characteristic, I'm receiving
status 133 in     `onCharacteristicWrite()`

I'm not sure why it is happening..!! Need some help..

I've tried to do the following, but they didn't make any impact:
-> adding `setWriteType` 
-> Changing the UUID to a private one

Do I have to get permissions before writing at client side?

Comment: Do you perform any operation e.g. readCharacteristic/writeCharacteristic in parallel? The BLE stack has problems with parallel execution, you should serialize them.

Comment: Do you use several connections in parallel? I got status 133, if tried to connect to more than seven devices.

Comment: Can you post the logcat output?

Comment: @Christopher I am scanning continuously even after connection has been made...Can it also cause the problem? I checked further and the problem seemed to be due to response code at server side, which I chose as different when sending response using sendResponse

Comment: Hmm, I do not think that this might cause the status 133. I do the same and it is no problem. Error 133 is only described as GATT_ERROR: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/stack/include/gatt_api.h

Answer (score 0):

I would start from checking the `property` of the `characteristics`.
Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888817/android-bluetooth-status-133-in-oncharacteristicwrite) thread for more information.

If the above actions does not help then try to verify that the `attributes` of the BLE server side are correct. For example: if you just connecting (with no pairing or bonding) then since it's an non-encrypted link the attributes of the characteristic shouldn't include any encryption enabled.